# Spring AOP advice not getting excuted

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I am new to Spring AOP and facing some issues in its implementation.

I am trying to implement logging as advice. But advice is not getting executed.

Following is the files I am using.

**LoggingAspect.java**

```
package com.demo.conference.aspects;

@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {
@Pointcut("execution(* com.demo.conference.daoImpl.ConferenceDAOImpl.*(..))")
public void point(){}


@Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))") //this should work for the public pointcut
private void anyPublicOperation() {}

@Before("anyPublicOperation()")
public void log(){
    System.out.println("--------------------->Aspect execuetd");

}
}
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

   <context:annotation-config/>
   <mvc:annotation-driven />
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.demo.conference"/>

 <bean id="hibernateTemplate"      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory"/>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

**applicationContext.xml**    // For AOP related config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">


   <context:component-scan base-package="com.demo.conference.aspects"/>
   <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
    <listener>
          <listener-class>
          org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
     </listener>

</web-app>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.11</version>
</dependency>                    
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.11</version>
</dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Firstly i was putting all xml configurations in single file(in dispatcher-servlet.xml), then it was throwing exception NoSuchBeanDefined.

Then i found in some post to declare AOP related config in seperate file. I did so.(If any one can explain the reason behind creating seperate files)
Now there is not any exception but Advice is not getting executed.

**Updated**

```
package com.demo.conference.daoImpl;
@Component
@Repository
public class ConferenceDAOImpl implements ConferenceDAO {

@Autowired
private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

/**
 * Method to list all the conferences
 * @return list of conferences
 */
public List<Conference> listConference() {
    System.out.println("***ConferenceDAOImpl : listConference");
    System.out.println("Before fetching conferences");
    List<Conference> conferenceList = hibernateTemplate.find("from "+ Conference.class.getName());

    return conferenceList;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `dispatcher-servlet.xml` change the component scan to `com.demo.conference.serviceControllers` and in `applicationContext.xml` change the component scan to `com.demo.conference`.

`HibernateTemplate` and other beans which are not web related shouldn't be placed in `dispatcher-servlet.xml`. These should be in `applicationContext.xml`. In `dispatcher-servlet.xml` you should have controllers, view resolvers and other beans related to web part only. Move any other beans to `applicationContext.xml` and configure the component-scans as I mentioned: in `dispatcher-servlet.xml` use `com.demo.conference.serviceControllers`, in `applicationContext.xml` use `com.demo.conference`.

The story is like this: beans in `dispatcher-servlet.xml` form an application context which has as a parent the application context formed by beans in `applicationContext.xml`. When a bean is needed by something in dispatcher-servlet context it is searched in the containing context, if it's not found it is searched in parent contexts. So, every bean defined in `applicationContext.xm`l should be easily accessible by beans in dispatcher-servlet context. But not vice-versa. Beans in applicationContext cannot access beans in dispatcher-servlet.

Also,  use `@Autowired` with the interfaces, not the concrete class: `@Autowired private ConferenceDAO dao;` and `@Autowired private ConferenceService service;` and restrict the range of your pointcut (use point() instead and comment anyPublicOperation())! Beans like HibernateTemplate are advised, as well, and Spring is creating a proxy for it. If you are injecting `HibernateTemplate` which is a concrete class in your own classes, the proxy which is created is a JDK proxy (which implements an interface) whereas `@Autowired` expects an instance of `HibernateTemplate`.