# Autowire @Component bean in a XML bean

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I'd like to autowire a bean annotated with `@Component` in a bean declared in the xml config.

**XML**

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="test" />

<bean id="testClass" class="test.TestClass"/>
```

**TestClass.java**

```
public class TestClass {
    @Autowired
    LocaleProvider locale;

    public void test() {
        locale.getMessage("test");
    }
}
```

**LocaleProvider.java**

```
@Component
public class LocaleProvider {
    ...

    public String getMessage(String key, Object... args) throws NoSuchMessageException {
        return ...;
    }
})
```

**TestController.java**

```
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @Autowired
    TestClass test;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public Object handle() {
        test.test();
    }
}
```

The xml bean is correctly created but the variable `locale` is always null...

**Stacktrace**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at test.TestClass.test(TestClass.java:16)   // = locale.getMessage("test");
    at test.TestController.handle(TestController.java:23)
```

**Log**

```
14:38:23,982 | INFO  | DefaultListableBeanFactory:577 | Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1ef6144: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0,_jsonConfigMapEditorConfigurer,_hibernateSerializationConfigPostProcessor,**testClass**,org.springframework.security.filterChains,org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0,org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0,org.springframework.security.web.PortResolverImpl#0,org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0,org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy#0,org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache#0,org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0,org.springframework.security.userDetailsServiceFactory,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1,sessionRegistry,org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0,org.springframework.security.authenticationManager,pathMatchingResourcePatternResolver]; root of factory hierarchy
...
14:38:24,002 | DEBUG | DefaultListableBeanFactory:217 | Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'testClass'
14:38:24,005 | DEBUG | DefaultListableBeanFactory:430 | Creating instance of bean 'testClass'
14:38:24,007 | DEBUG | DefaultListableBeanFactory:504 | Eagerly caching bean 'testClass' to allow for resolving potential circular references
14:38:24,012 | DEBUG | DefaultListableBeanFactory:458 | Finished creating instance of bean 'testClass'
...
14:38:24,970 | INFO  | DefaultListableBeanFactory:577 | Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@ef96bc: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,**localeProvider**,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0,viewResolver,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#1,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#1,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#2,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#2,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#3,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#3,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#4,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#4,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#5,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#5,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1ef6144
...
14:38:24,993 | DEBUG | DefaultListableBeanFactory:217 | Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'localeProvider'
14:38:24,995 | DEBUG | DefaultListableBeanFactory:430 | Creating instance of bean 'localeProvider'
14:38:24,996 | DEBUG | DefaultListableBeanFactory:504 | Eagerly caching bean 'localeProvider' to allow for resolving potential circular references
14:38:25,007 | DEBUG | DefaultListableBeanFactory:458 | Finished creating instance of bean 'localeProvider'
...
14:38:25,008 | DEBUG | InjectionMetadata         :61 | Found injected element on class [test.TestController]: AutowiredFieldElement for test.TestClass test.TestController.test
14:38:25,008 | DEBUG | DefaultListableBeanFactory:504 | Eagerly caching bean 'testController' to allow for resolving potential circular references
14:38:25,016 | DEBUG | InjectionMetadata         :90 | Processing injected method of bean 'testController': AutowiredFieldElement for test.TestClass test.TestController.test
14:38:25,017 | DEBUG | DefaultListableBeanFactory:245 | Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'testClass'
14:38:25,017 | DEBUG | AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor:432 | Autowiring by type from bean name 'testController' to bean named 'testClass'
```

If I declare `LocaleProvider` in the xml, it works fine. Also, if I annotate `TestClass` with `@Component`, it also works fine. I need to do annotation + xml mix configuration.

How could I resolve this ?

**Environnement :**

- Glassfish 3.1
- Spring 3.1.3
- Spring Security 3.1.3

Comment: show some code. How you define your bean in XML ahd how do you set the value in code

Comment: Also please make sure you do not use the injected fields in the constructor. Use `@PostConstruct` if you need to invoke them right after the bean has been initialized

Comment: @Stéphane Nicoll : Just added some code. @Grove : I do not use injected fields in the constructor as you can see and I think there's no need to use `@PostConstruct` actually. Thanks anyway.

Comment: By the way, `LocaleProvider` works correctly in another bean which is annotated with `@Component`.

Comment: How do you get an instance of `TestClass`?

Comment: Just did another edit to add `TestController` and the stacktrace.

Comment: Are you sure you're not overwriting the autowired `test` field in your `TestController` somewhere, or the `locale` inside the `TestClass`? Because this should work perfectly fine, otherwise Spring would complain if it didn't find an autowire candidate for the dependency

Comment: `test` field is not overwrote (`locale` either), I use the same code as I posted. Actually, I also think this should work... but it's not :( I edit my post to add the log, maybe it will help.

Comment: I found the issue : I have defined `annotation-config` and `component-scan` in `dispatcher-servlet.xml` and `testClass` was defined in `application-context.xml`. I merged them in `application-context.xml` and it works... finally. Thanks to all who tried to help.

Comment: For more explanation, see Bozho's answer :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549034/dispatcher-servlet-xml-and-application-context-xml

Comment: The idea is not to have a single .xml file how you end up doing by merging the files, but to structure and design your packages and classes so that in dispatcher-servlet.xml to have things web related and in application-context.xml to have the other beans. See in [my answer to another post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034667/spring-aop-advice-not-getting-excuted/24036865#24036865) today some suggestions on how to setup a Spring web app a bit more correct.

Comment: Thanks for your point of view. I'll keep your answer in my favorite links but for this project, I don't really need parent/child context.